# Program to play Magic: the Gathering

Tags: games, alternative

What program does people use to play Magic: the Gathering on Ubuntu, against human players, for free? None of the programs I've tried works.

This is what I've found so far. I'll link to the projects later:

- **Forge**: Written in Java. Looks and works amazing, but is *only single player*. It's almost as good as wtc's official modo client.
- **MAGE**: Written in Java. Has online multiplayer support. I can get it to start, but the interface is so flaky and weird that I dont understand how to play a duel or build a deck.

Comment: I understand that some people are resistant to this, but when it comes to games I find it's more trouble to try *not* to use Wine than to just suck it up and do it. apt-get install wine1.5, check the compatibility listing at winehq for the game in question, and just do it. You may want to avoid fullscreen modes, but overall I think you'll be surprised at how well it works.

Comment: Wine is ok but it just have to WORK. So many of the projects I've found are just broken in strange ways or abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

gCCG works flawlessly and is open source + native... Quirky controls from the start, but once you figure it all out you'll like it, and there are a lot of players.

We're trying to remedy all this at WTactics.org, but don't have a client for you yet... also, as mentioned, Cockatrice also works wonders.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to play M:tG on Ubuntu for free via the advice in [this link](http://forums.mtgsalvation.com/showthread.php?t=8680).

From a quick glance over them, none of the programs in the link seem to natively support Linux/Ubuntu. It may be possible to use these applications via WINE/Play On Linux.

An alternative to going through a Windows application and using WINE/POL is [Cockatrice](http://jeffhoogland.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/playing-magic-gathering-on-linux-with.html) which seems to use .deb packages so should be fairly simple to setup. The problem is - the official website appears to be down currently (as of 27th of February 2013) for legal reasons. If you check [this link](http://tappedout.net/mtg-forum/general/cockatrice-alternate/) you may find out more.

The final alternative is to use a platform such as [Roll20](http://www.roll20.net). The Roll20 platform is built with table-top games in mind. In fact, I played a few DnD games on there with no issues. Because it's web based, there's no operating system compatibility issue, either. When I last used it, it only really supported Chrome, however.

Quick run through:

First method requires WINE.

Second method is down, but check the last link of that section!

Finally, with some major set-up you can do it via a web platform.

Hopefully one of these gives you an idea as to do!

Good luck!